# find non- common elements between two string arrays

Tags: java

There was a problem that is How to find non- common elements between two string arrays. Eg:

```
String[] a = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}; 
String[] b = {"b", "c"}; 
// O/p should be a,d
```

I have tried the below approach but please advise is there any other efficient way to achieve the same

```
String[] a = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
String[] b = {"b", "c"};

Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(a.length);
for (String s : a) {
    set.add(s);
}
for (String s : b) {
    set.remove(s);
}
return set;
```

please advise is there any other efficient approach also we can achieve this in java

Comment: In the example above `b` is a subset of `a`. What output do you expect when this is not the case?

Comment: http://java67.blogspot.de/2014/05/how-to-compare-two-arrays-in-java-string-int-example.html read this and you will find what you need to do.

Comment: Given the problem that you stated, your solution is not correct. What if "e" was in string[] b?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems the most effective way using Java. Still, you can make it shorter by using [`addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-), [`removeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) and [`retainAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-)

```
String[] a = {"a","b","c","d"};
String[] b = {"b", "c"};

//this is to avoid calling Arrays.asList multiple times
List<String> aL = Arrays.asList(a);
List<String> bL = Arrays.asList(b);

//finding the common element for both
Set<String> common = new HashSet<>(aL);
common.retainAll(bL);

//now, the real uncommon elements
Set<String> uncommon = new HashSet<>(aL);
uncommon.addAll(bL);
uncommon.removeAll(common);
return uncommon;
```

Running sample: http://ideone.com/Fxgshp

Comment: is this different from the method used in the question ?

Comment: @mohaned *That seems the most effective way using Java. **Still, you can make it shorter**.*

Comment: I know it's shorter but is it more efficient ?

Comment: @mohaned it's the same, just less code... That's why I replied to your question with the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Apache Commons Lang3 library's [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html), you can do this:

```
String[] nonCommon = ArrayUtils.addAll(
        ArrayUtils.removeElements(a, b), 
        ArrayUtils.removeElements(b, a));
```

I can't speak to its performance efficiency, but it *is* more efficient to write since it's a single line of code and you don't need to create and manipulate Sets.

This approach captures distinct elements in array `b` as well, as shown in this Groovy test case

```
@Grab('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2')
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils

String[] a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
String[] b = ["b", "c", "e"]

assert ["a", "d", "e"] == ArrayUtils.addAll(ArrayUtils.removeElements(a, b), ArrayUtils.removeElements(b, a))
```

Comment: You might want to update your link to http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons Collections `CollectionUtils` has a method called [disjunction()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#disjunction(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable)) that will do exactly what you want.